# t-sql XML parse out to multiple records with event and data and value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm trying to parse this out. I want one record for each event, so I need a way to query each event separately.

But I'd like it to look something like this:

```
Event Name                                         || ID  || Timestamp || process_utilization
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scheduler_monitor_system_heal_ring_buffer_recorded ||  0  || 0         || 33
```

Here's the XML:

```
<events>
  <session startTime="2012-09-06T10:48:15.373" droppedEvents="0" largestDroppedEvent="0">
    <RingBufferTarget truncated="0" processingTime="0" totalEventsProcessed="14" eventCount="14" droppedCount="0" memoryUsed="3994">
      <event name="scheduler_monitor_system_health_ring_buffer_recorded" package="sqlos" timestamp="2012-09-19T16:46:33.091Z">
        <data name="id">
          <type name="uint32" package="package0" />
          <value>0</value>
        </data>
        <data name="timestamp">
          <type name="uint64" package="package0" />
          <value>0</value>
        </data>
        <data name="process_utilization">
          <type name="uint32" package="package0" />
          <value>33</value>
        </data>
      </event>
      <event name="resource_monitor_ring_buffer_recorded" package="sqlos" timestamp="2012-09-19T16:46:38.386Z">
        <data name="id">
          <type name="uint32" package="package0" />
          <value>0</value>
        </data>
      </event>
    </RingBufferTarget>
  </session>
</events>
```

EDIT:
Alternatively, if we could return rows that look like this, that would be Just Fine:

```
scheduler_monitor_system_heal_ring_buffer_recorded || id || 0
scheduler_monitor_system_heal_ring_buffer_recorded || timestamp || 0
scheduler_monitor_system_heal_ring_buffer_recorded || process_utilization|| 33
```

EDIT: (Thanks, Mark)
Using Mark's code, I got this which is 98% of what I want - just need the Event Name.

```
SELECT
    DataName = Evt.value('@name[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    TypeName= Evt.value('type[1]/@name[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    DataValue = Evt.value('value[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    DataText = Evt.value('text[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/events/session/RingBufferTarget/event/data') as Tbl(Evt)
```

which returns:

```
id                  uint32  0   NULL
timestamp           uint64  0   NULL
process_utilization uint32  33  NULL
id                  uint32  0   NULL
```

(but, obviously, need the event name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your XML in a variable called `@input`, try this:

```
declare @input XML = '....(your XML here).....';

SELECT
    EventName = Evt.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    EventID = Evt.value('(data[@name="id"]/value)[1]', 'int'),
    EventTimeStamp = Evt.value('(data[@name="timestamp"]/value)[1]', 'bigint'),
    ProcessUtilization = Evt.value('(data[@name="process_utilization"]/value)[1]', 'int')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/events/session/RingBufferTarget/event') as Tbl(Evt)
```

With your sample XML, I get an output of:

```
EventName                                           EventID   EventTimeStamp ProcessUtilization
scheduler_monitor_system_health_ring_buffer_record     0          0              33
resource_monitor_ring_buffer_recorded                  0         NULL            NULL
```

Comment: Marc, that's almost exactly what I want, and will work as a fallback.  What if there's 30 of the "sets", not just id/timestamp/process_utilization?  Is there some way to have it autogenerate each column, rather than invoking the name specifically `(data[@name="id"]/value)[1]` for each one?

Comment: Alternatively: multiple rows would be fine, provided you can tie event name to them.

Comment: And alternatively to that, since each "data" would have a name/type/value, could you put those all in one column?  Let me keep messing with your code, it may just be a slight variation.

Answer (score 2):

Many many thanks to @Marc_S for pointing me in the right direction!  Marc, if there's some way for you to get credit, add an answer here or whatever and I'll credit you.

```
SELECT
    DataName = Evt.value('../@name[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    DataName = Evt.value('@name[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    TypeName= Evt.value('type[1]/@name[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    DataValue = Evt.value('value[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    DataText = Evt.value('text[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/events/session/RingBufferTarget/event/data') as Tbl(Evt)
```

Comment: +1 great to have helped you find the solution that works for you!